# Levene test for equal variance

Tags: variance, anova, pvalue

I would like to run one-way ANOVA test on my data. I saw that one of several assumptions for one-way ANOVA  is that there needs to be homogeneity of variances. I have run the test for different data-sets. I find sometimes my p-values are larger than 0.05 and for some datasets it is smaller.

As I understand, if the p-value is smaller than 0.05, then I can reject the null hypothesis and tell that the variances are not equal (and then it makes sense to use ANOVA?)

The problem is that I see in different sources diferent conclusions: in some they run ANOVA if  they reject the null hypothesis, for some they run ANOVA if they cannot reject the null hypotheis. For example,

[here](https://medium.com/@kyawsawhtoon/levenes-test-the-assessment-for-equality-of-variances-94503b695a57) it says that if is smaller we can run the ANOVA:
[image]

But [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/When-do-I-use-the-Levenes-Test-with-one-way-ANOVA) it recommended that p-value>0.05

To me, intuitively, it sounds like p-value should be greater than 0.05 but I would like to get clear answer regarding  that.

Comment: indicate Levene formulas and assumptions. What is the specific purpose of ANOVA and Levene test.